# Cannot insert record in remote database - Linked server

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I want to insert record into a table in my remote database table.

Comment: Is this a standalone tsql for insert or part of something else?

Comment: What version of SQL Server is this? Have you looked at this known issue: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/668009/using-linked-servers-ms-sql-2005-this-operation-conflicts-with-another-pending-operation-on-this-transaction

Comment: Did you check your login has the write access in the linked server? Due to you can select from the table, it means your connection has no problem. Right?

Comment: yes i can select. but cant insert. how to check if i have write access?

Comment: @SqlWorldWide I have 2 servers/instances, both SQL Authentication.

Comment: @The sK, SqlWorldWide was asking you another thing. The question is: do you perform ONLY THIS ONE INSERT that you showed us in your post, or do you perform some actions and the INSERT stetement is only a part of your code?

Answer (score 1):

Ooo, bad news - this means you're using a trigger:

```
from ZTable Zh
inner join inserted
```

If you're trying to work in a trigger, that means there are other changes to other tables in your transaction. The "inserted" table you're using means that you're working with inserted records from another table.

This means you're trying to do a distributed transaction: committing multiple changes on different servers at the same time. This is a recipe for slow performance.

Take a step back and consider the business problem you're trying to solve. For example, if you're trying to log inserts, consider logging on the same table rather than trying to coordinate transactions across multiple SQL Servers. Or, consider using a built-in feature like Change Data Capture or Change Tracking.

There's a chance, depending on your SQL Server version, that it's fixed by [this SQL Server 2005 issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/668009/using-linked-servers-ms-sql-2005-this-operation-conflicts-with-another-pending-operation-on-this-transaction), but even if it is - I'd recommend a different approach than triggers that call linked servers.

Comment: No, we aren't actually trying to log. We just need to make a transaction from one instance to another. It cannot be compromised sadly.
Is there any other way? how can i make this work? any suggestion please?

Comment: Rather than doing a trigger, consider adding a row to a table on the same table, and run a queue based app to process the changes in that table.

Comment: can you please give me any link for tutorial? or any info related to queue based run?

Comment: IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM myQueueTable WHERE IsProcessed = 0) BEGIN do some stuff END